# Ways to open a Lens as raw data table rather than the bar chart

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics-cloud

When I click on "Open as Lens" in a dashboard, the Lens opens up in a bar chart. Is there anyway to display it as raw data table, rather than the default bar chart?

Answer (score 1):

There's a new [Expert Editor mode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_modify.htm) in Spring 16 release which should let you see all the JSON data.

You need to follow these steps

> 1) To access Expert Editor Mode, open the lens or dashboard you want
>   to edit, and press CTRL+E for PCs or CMD+E for Macs.
>
> 2) If the Reload JSON button is available, click it to load the
>   current running lens or dashboard.
>
> 3) Reload JSON loads the code of the currently running lens or
>   dashboard. This button is available whenever the JSON in the editor
>   doesn’t match the running JSON, which can happen when you first open
>   the editor.
>
> 4) Modify the JSON in the editor. You can use standard keyboard
>   shortcuts for editing functions and search.
>
> 5) To go back to the explorer and see how edits to the JSON appear in
>   the lens or dashboard, click Switch to Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

create a lense for raw data table first. then in the dashboard use the values table option and drag the raw data table into it. this will help